# MySQL - Simple queries are really slow sometimes

Tags: mysql

I have some issues with my MySQL server

```
# Time: 2017-10-30T09:25:41.253828Z
# User@Host: dbXXXXXXXXXXXX[dbXXXXXXXXXXXX] @ localhost []  Id:   469
# Query_time: 26.990475  Lock_time: 0.000039 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use dbXXXXXXXXXXXX;
SET timestamp=1509355541;
UPDATE online SET last_ping=1509355514 WHERE `device`='wggggn4gggk2gggggXYgEokgggggpOggf';
```

The table is super-simple and contains around 1000 rows
https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GRjN6fE.png

I have no idea why it takes so long sometimes. The *last_ping* is updated every 5 seconds when the device is online.

Or this one from WordPress:

```
# Time: 2017-10-30T07:55:24.755752Z
# User@Host: sobotiste[sobotiste] @ localhost []  Id: 22317
# Query_time: 9.586909  Lock_time: 0.000113 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use sobotiste;
SET timestamp=1509350124;
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = '1509351915' WHERE `option_name` = '_transient_timeout_4__974818834';
```

What should I do?

Version of server (from PMA):

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_type=1
long_query_time=8
slow_query_log=ON
query_cache_limit=32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
join_buffer_size=512K
max_heap_table_size=64M
tmp_table_size=64M
table_open_cache=1024
innodb_lru_scan_depth=256
key_buffer_size=32M
```

Comment: Could you please describe the environment? OS, hypervisor, disk configuration. MySQL startup options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have performance problems you have to see the entire picture to understand where you can optimize. Focusing on one single symptom will hide other important details you are missing.

Usually on Wordpress, each SQL query is running in a single transaction. This means that the UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT/ALTER query returns that is it completed only after the data is on disk.

The query could be affected by other queries that are locking rows or tables, but this is not the case for you because Lock_time is low.

This means that this simple query is the problem by itself. This query depends on the disk system to be fast. 
Your MySQL disk speed will be affected by other clients using it, like:

- other VMs using the same disk array
- other processes on the same machine or on a different machine which uses the same disk array
- background check and recovery on disk array
- storage migration at array or hypervisor level

What can you do from inside your machine. First determine if you are running inside a VM. If it is a VM chances that it is shared with other tenants are very high.

Check the latency on the disk. For Linux run `iostat -x 1` and look on `await` column. Should be as low as possible. For Windows check https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2012/02/07/measuring-disk-latency-with-windows-performance-monitor-perfmon/

A latency over 200ms is high.

Remember that the performance depends on your perception. In 2000 the performance of a fast application would be considered slow today.

Comment: It's running on Microsoft Azure (4 cores, 8GB RAM). You can look at stats from Munin (https://www.pinf.sk/ihost/d/1509366954-1160019329.png)

Comment: The disk is sometimes slow. Munin is showing average for a time frame of 5 minutes or more. This means you will see the 1-5 seconds when the storage was frozen and the data will be smoother by average. So 167.37ms wait time in average could be a few seconds of waiting on storage.

Comment: Is there a way I can make the disk faster?

Comment: Yes. Use SSD. Use newer SSD. Use the disk only for your application. Make statistics on the disk read/write operation sizes and change the strip size and cluster size to make is smaller or bigger. Use RAID10 instead of RAID5 or 6.
Another solution is avoiding the disk. Do you need to run those queries? If the data is only for statistics, why not caching the data into memory and write in one single update once per minute.
Another solution if you do not care about the consistency of the data to write those queries to run asynchronous so that the web pages are not waiting for them.